# Как быстро и легко переводить картинки на ПК?

Tags: google-translate

Как я понял из тестов самым лучшим на данный момент переводчиком с картинки является приложение для android, google translate. (yandex-не видит тест, SCREEN TRANSLATOR-не видит тест, New OCR-Думает что m это n, img2txt-коверкает слова)
Но проблема в том что google translate работает только на android. Я пробовал запустить его через BlueStacks но код выдает ошибку e-5105 или e-807. Единственное что более менее работает у меня это связка AirDroid, AutoIt Window Info, AutoIt , Ножницы, Проводник, Opera. Но код написанный на AutoIt работает медленно и не очень стабильно в связке с AirDroid.

Вариант использовать

https://lens.google.com/

https://cloud.google.com/vision/

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr

Мне не подходит так как. Я не хочу привязывать свою карту и платить за это. Бесплатная версия тоже не подходит так как имеет серьезные ограничения.

У кого есть идеи как еще можно организовать это?

Comment: cv2 на питоне вроде может видеть текст. а перевод уже парсером делать

Answer (score 1):

Пару раз была нужна в подобного рода инструменте. Я переводил текст при помощи сервиса [**img2txt**](https://img2txt.com).
Всё достаточно просто:

Я выбрал вот такую картинку для перевода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открываем сервис, ссылку на который я указал чуть выше, загружаем картинку с текстом, который нужно перевести, выбираем язык текста, который **на картинке**.

[image: Выбор языка]

Всё почти готово. Кликаем "Загрузить" и автоматически перенаправляемся на страницу, на которой содержится распознанный текст с картинки.

[image: Результат распознавания]

И дальше уже решайте куда и как загрузить полученный результат. Если нужен перевод - пожалуйста. Нажимаем "Перевести текст" и перенаправляемся на Google Переводчик, который уже сделал то, что нам нужно - перевёл!

[image: Переведённый текст]

Профит!

Comment: По сути любой распознаватель текста может перевести картинку в текст если конечно текст ровный и в большом разрешении Но к сожжению у меня не такой текст. Результат теста `img2txt.`-Aiioht, tine to put the oid ir to. work, `New OCR`- Airight, tine to put the old girl to work. `google`-Alright, time to put the old girl to work.